# Marketplace site: how to verify an account is who it says it is?

Tags: payment, verification, marketplace

I'm working on a project for philanthropists to donate to many different charities through a single website.

When charities sign up on my site, I need some way to make sure they are who they say they are, so that when I send money from donors, I know the money goes to the right person.

For example, if somebody signs up as the American Red Cross, and then a donor wants to send money to the American red Cross, I want to make sure that the money is going to the real American Red Cross, and not some enterprising scoundrel.

I need suggestions for how to do this verification.  Here are some ideas so far:

- mail a postcard with a unique code to the official address of the charity (this is what couchsurfing does)
- require some tiny bank transaction
- do a phone call to the main charity

Please help me out!  What other ways can I use to verify that a charity's information is correct!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start the charity registration process with one simple field: EIN. You can download the IRS's database of charity organizations here:
http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/mainSearch.do;jsessionid=X44scb0f6CnRe-7icQF2rQ__?mainSearchChoice=pub78&dispatchMethod=selectSearch

have the user provide EIN, and then you can query for all the organization's address info and verify identity. That would allow you to pre-populate much of the registration form on the next page. Because you'd probably have some brand-spanking-new organizations that aren't in the database yet, you could handle exceptions with a message that their verification will take extra time, and you could take those cases offline.